# Java how develope a jar plugin with jdbc driver inside

Tags: java, jdbc, jar, classpath, classloader

I'm developing a plugin jar for my server application. I'd like that this plugin contains jdbc driver inside to access the dbms.

This is the code in the plugin to load the jdbc:

```
URL url = PLugin.class.getResource("mysql-connector-java-5.1.22.jar");
    log.debug("Url: "+url.getPath());
    URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { url }, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", true, ucl);
```

Executing this code from a main method in the plugin itself works fine.

This is how I load the jar into my server application:

```
File pluginFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") +  File.separator + "plugins" + File.separator + fileJar);       
    if (pluginFile != null && pluginFile.exists() && pluginFile.canRead()) {
        try {
            URL[] urls = { new URL("jar:file:" + pluginFile.getAbsolutePath() + "!/") };
            ClassLoader uc = new URLClassLoader(urls, this.getClass().getClassLoader());

            JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(pluginFile);
            Enumeration<JarEntry> e = jarFile.entries();
            while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
                JarEntry je = (JarEntry) e.nextElement();
                if (je.isDirectory() || !je.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
                    continue;
                }
                // -6 because of .class
                String className = je.getName().substring(0, je.getName().length() - 6);
                className = className.replace('/', '.');
                Class clazz = uc.loadClass(className);

                return clazz.newInstance();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("",e);
        }
    } else {
        log.error("File " + pluginFile.getAbsolutePath() + " not found");
    }
```

In short I read the jar file and I load the first file.class inside (there is only 1 file .class inside every plugin.jar) and then I create an instance of that class (that is the same of the code above.
The plugins are in a folder outside the classhpath of the server application.

Unfortunally doing this I've always this exception:

```
24/07/2014 19:26:00 ERROR PluginManager:68 - 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
    ....
    ....
```

I guess that this is a classpath problem but I'm not sure how can be solved.

Thanks

Comment: Do you provide the driver jar on the classpath? If not you might have to put it there. Another option might be to make your plugin a fat jar, i.e. copy the driver classes into your plugin (there are build tools like Maven which help you with this), but if you have multiple of those jars you might run into class loading problems.

Comment: Say that the plugin is plugin.jar and is in the home folder of the user (so outside the classpath). Inside plugin.jar I've my Plugin.class and a driver (say mysql-connector-java-5.1.22.jar). Howewer I can have many plugins (plugin1.jar, plugin2.jar) and some plugins can have the same driver inside. Any suggestion about how to manage this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in this way:

Inside my server side app I load my jar plugin:

```
File pluginFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "ecall" + File.separator + "plugins" + File.separator + fileJar);
    if (pluginFile != null && pluginFile.exists() && pluginFile.canRead()) {
        try {
            JarClassLoader jcl = new JarClassLoader();
            jcl.add(pluginFile.getPath());
            JclObjectFactory factory = JclObjectFactory.getInstance();

            JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(pluginFile);
            try {

                Enumeration<JarEntry> e = jarFile.entries();
                while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
                    JarEntry je = (JarEntry) e.nextElement();
                    if (je.isDirectory() || !je.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    // -6 because of .class
                    String className = je.getName().substring(0, je.getName().length() - 6);
                    className = className.replace('/', '.');
                    Object obj = factory.create(jcl, className);
                    jarFile.close();
                    return obj;
                }
            } finally {
                jarFile.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("", e);
        }
```

in the method that need to access the external db of my plugin.jar I do:

```
    JarClassLoader jcl = new JarClassLoader();
    jcl.add(".");
    JclObjectFactory factory = JclObjectFactory.getInstance();
    // Create object of loaded class
    Object obj = factory.create(jcl, dataSet.getDriver());
    DriverManager.registerDriver(new JdbcDriver((Driver) obj));

    Connection con = null;
    if (dataSet.getUsername() != null && !dataSet.getUsername().isEmpty()) {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(dataSet.getUrl(), dataSet.getUsername(), dataSet.getPassword());
    } else {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(dataSet.getUrl());
    }
```

where JdbcDriver is a custom class:

```
public class JdbcDriver implements Driver {
private Driver driver;

public JdbcDriver(Driver d) {
    this.driver = d;
}

public boolean acceptsURL(String u) throws SQLException {
    return this.driver.acceptsURL(u);
}

public Connection connect(String u, Properties p) throws SQLException {
    return this.driver.connect(u, p);
}

public int getMajorVersion() {
    return this.driver.getMajorVersion();
}

public int getMinorVersion() {
    return this.driver.getMinorVersion();
}

public DriverPropertyInfo[] getPropertyInfo(String u, Properties p) throws SQLException {
    return this.driver.getPropertyInfo(u, p);
}

public boolean jdbcCompliant() {
    return this.driver.jdbcCompliant();
}

@Override
public java.util.logging.Logger getParentLogger() throws SQLFeatureNotSupportedException {
    return this.driver.getParentLogger();
}
```

}

I hope this can be helpful for others that have the same problem.